# Which instance will receive the notification if there are two instances of same controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I'm firing a notification from the same controller and receiving it in the same controller.
I'm using a common controller whose one instance is created first and then pushed into the stack and then the other one.
So what I was expecting is that I should be receiving the notification in both instances but in this case I'm only receiving the notification in second instance which is lower down the stack. But when there is only one instance then I'm receiving the notification in the same controller just like it should be.

Can anybody explain me the reason why this is happening?

Comment: Is it possible that you discard the listener upon viewDidDisappear or viewWillDisappear? In this case only the currently visible controller would receive the notification

Comment: You should be receiving on both. Just make sure both instance started observing

Comment: Can you the code on how you fire the notification and how you register to this notification ?

Comment: both will receive, all the viewcontrollers listening to that notification.

Comment: I haven't removed the listener on viewDidDisapper. @ArikSegal

Comment: @RintoAndrews I was also expecting that but it's not happening.